# Is Validation on Models in Backbone only done when set on an instance?

Tags: validation, backbone.js

I have created an object:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    'name': '',
    'age': 0
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('error', function(model, error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
  validate: function(attributes){
    if (attributes.name == '') {
      return "How do we call him!?";
    }
  },
  changeName: function(name) {
    this.set({'name':name});
  },
  getOlder: function() {
    this.set({'age': this.get('age') +1});
  }   
});
```

I create an instance of Person and put in a blank on the name and I never received an error. But when I set a blank name on an already created instance, it fired the validation.

```
var teejay = new Person;
teejay.changeName('');
=> How do we call him!?
teejay.get('name');
=> ""
```

From what I am seeing from the Backbone source code, I see

```
this.set(attributes, {silent: true});
```

Is it right to assume that validation is only done whenever attributes are changed or set?

Comment: "validate is called before set and save" as per backbone's documentation. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone will always call the `validate` method when you `set` or `save` an attribute with the exception of when you pass in a hash to the constructor or when the model instantiates with the `default` hash.

e.g.

```
var myperson = new Person({name: ''});
```

Will NOT call the `validate` method since the constructor MUST return a new instance of the model.

However,

```
var myperson = new Person();
myperson.set('name', '');
```

Will.

Your `validate` method will never print out anything -- the `return` on validate is used to test whether or not it worked.  If you return anything "truthy" validation will fail, but that's it.  It's up to you to trigger the `'error'` message or whatever else you want.

What you're seeing is exactly as should be expected.

TL;DR:
Your `defaults` hash will not ever be validated since it has to return a valid model.

(Also, allow me to shill for my [Backbone.Validator](https://toddself.github.com/Backbone.Validator) project now -- don't write your own!)