# Backbone inheritance - deep copying

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js

I've seen this question regarding inheritance in Backbone: 
[Backbone.js view inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735133/backbone-js-view-inheritance). Useful but doesn't answer my question.

The problem I'm experiencing is this:

Say I have a class `Panel` (**model** in this example);

```
var Panel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        name : 'my-panel'
    }
});
```

And then an `AdvancedPanel`;

```
var AdvancedPanel = Panel.extend({
    defaults : {
        label : 'Click to edit'
    }
});
```

The following doesn't work:

```
var advancedPanel = new AdvancedPanel();
alert(advancedPanel.get('name')); // Undefined :(
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hWmnb/

I guess I can see that I can achieve this myself through some custom *extend* function that creates a deep copy of the prototype, but this seems like a common thing that people might want from Backbone inheritance, is there a standard way of doing it?

Comment: I tried what is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549149/extending-the-defaults-of-a-model-superclass-in-backbone-js in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vesteraas/EXbnb/

Comment: Ah thanks, I hadn't seen this answer/queston but now that I see it is a linked one. That's useful although still not that clean...I feel that since 'defaults' is standard Backbone model property, it should be dealt with by the extend. I guess not the case. Any other suggestions out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking this up, I have written a simple `advancedExtend` method to replace the line (from [this inheritance construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735133/backbone-js-view-inheritance#answer-7736030)):

```
Panel.extend = Backbone.Model.extend;
```

with:

```
Panel.extend = advancedExtend;
```

My `advancedExtend` method looks like this:

```
function advancedExtend(protoProps, classProps) {

    var delegate = this.render ? 
                        Backbone.View : (this.save ? 
                            Backbone.Model : (this.navigate ? 
                                Backbone.Router : Backbone.Collection)); 

    var child = delegate.extend.apply(this, [ protoProps, classProps ]);

    _.defaults(child.prototype.defaults, this.prototype.defaults);
    _.defaults(child.prototype.events, this.prototype.events);
    _.defaults(child.prototype.attributes, this.prototype.attributes);

    return child;
};
```

*N.B. I realise the definition of `delegate` is pointless since all of the Backbone prototype `extend` methods are the same, but figured this might be more robust for future versions.*

See the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/edslocombe/AgXdw/).

I would be interested to hear what Backbone veterans think of this approach, given that it is non-standard...

Answer (score 3):

The Backbone `extend` function which sets up the prototype chain,
among other things, is generic and is used for views, routers, models,
and collections. So it doesn't know about specifics like `defaults`
or `events` and cannot determine if the extending type wants to **override**
or **merge** the value in the parent.

One way forward is to do this explicitly outside of the actual definition:

```
AdvancedPanel.prototype.defaults = _.extend({}, Panel.prototype.defaults, {
  label: 'Click me'
});
```

You would to the same with views:

```
SomeExtendedView.prototype.events = _.extend({}, SomeBaseView.prototype.events, {
  'click button': 'onClick'
});
```

You can actually have the defaults listed at their apropriate place as well,
if you like. You just do the merging outside of the constructor definition:

```
var Base = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    base: 123
  }
});

var Extended = Base.extend({
  defaults: {
    extended: 456
  }
});

Extended.prototype.defaults = _.extend({}, Base.prototype.defaults, Extended.prototype.defaults);
```

This will have the `Extended.defaults` include both `base`, `extended` and
whatever attributes passed to the instantiation:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Extended({ test: 'Hey' }).toJSON()));
>> {"base":123,"extended":456,"test":"Hey"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with JavaScript you don't have classical inheritance, so you'll need to do something special here.

When you use `_.extend` the object in the list that is farthest to the "right" of objects you're extending will "win" in any name collision.

What you need to do is either override the definition of extend to handle these cases, or name your `defaults` hash something like `local_defaults` and merge them in your `initialization` method

```
    initialize: function(options){
        var attrs = _.extend({}, this.defaults, this.local_defaults);
        this.set(attrs, {silent: true});
    },
```

Something like that. You have to set the attributes hash to the set of defaults; normally this happens in the constructor for the model, but the model only knows about defaults at that point.

Of course if you redefine a default in your local_defaults, you'll still overwrite, so then you'd be looking into overwriting extend. (Which we've done for a few specific cases here at work, so happy to help if you need with that.)

Comment: Would this really work? At the time the `initialize` function is called I think the attributes (and `previousAttributes` for dirty tracking) are already set from the defaults together with the actual data, which you overwrite in the code above on each instantiation.

Comment: @Greg Argh, sorry was typing fast.  Updated to what we're using in production code.  Similar, but a little different.  Uses `set` instead of directly modifying `this.attributes`. But yes, we use this in production right now, so it definitely does work :)

Comment: Not trying to be picky here, but at the time initialize is called, any data attributes passed to the constructor would have already been set on the model. Setting the defaults at that point, wouldn't that override those attributes? `new AdvancedPanel({ name: "A", label: "B"})` would be overwritten with the defaults all the time?

Comment: @Greg Yes. But being that validation does not occur when setting values thought the constructor, it's a bad idea to set them that way. If you can't validate your data, that's always a big problem. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658441/is-validation-on-models-in-backbone-only-done-when-set-on-an-instance/12678183#12678183

Comment: I agree that when collecting information from the user, you should use `set` (I actually upvoted your linked answer yesterday), but when fetching a collection from the server where the data is already validated, the constructor is used by `Backbone.Collection` to instantiate the models where the attributes are passed directly in to the constructor. Setting the defaults in `initialize` will override those attributes.

Comment: @greg Ah.  Yes.  We're only dealing with user-gen content.  Hadn't thought about that! Thanks for showing the bad side effects!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways about going this, but the preferred way in my applications is to define 'defaults' on a model as a function, so you could do something along these lines:

```
var Panel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        name : 'my-panel'
    }
});
```

just defined your extended model as such:

```
var AdvancedPanel = Panel.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        var d = _.result(Panel.prototype, 'defaults'); // doing this as top level might be a function as well
        return _.extend({}, d, {
            label : 'Click to edit' 
        });
    }
});
```

and then in the console you should get the correct value for name

```
var advancedPanel = new AdvancedPanelModel();
console.log('advancedPanel', advancedPanel.get('name'));
```

and that should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is what I shall do. Though I still have a bit of an issue with it, maybe I'm expecting too much from Backbone...it seems to me that if Backbone provides an `extend` function on a Model (and others), then standard Model properties should be also considered in the inheritance.

Comment: If you don't want the defaults-function to be invoked on each model instantiation you could also initialize the advanced defaults once using something like `AdvancedPanel.prototype.defaults = _.extend(Panel.prototype.defaults, { **advanced defaults here** });` after the definition of `AdvancedPanel`. You would to the same if you want to extend the `events` hash.